# What are the reasons that the `FavoriteCount` column in the `Posts` table has elements that are not available?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I was taking a look at this post which details the database schema for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. I had one question about the `Posts` data set: what are the reasons that the `FavoriteCount` column has elements that are not available?

At first, I thought that this could be completely explained by the `PostTypeId` column--after all, if the post wasn't a question, it can't be favorited. However, I noticed that there are some questions that have a `NA` value, even though they're questions. Why is this?